Proof Verification: If $p^k m^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $p$, then $p \equiv 1 \pmod 8$ holds.
Let $p^k m^2$ be an odd perfect number with special prime $p$.
Since $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ must hold, then $m^2 - p^k \equiv 0 \pmod 4$.
It follows that
$$m^2 - p^k = a^2 - b^2 = (a - b)(a + b)$$
for some positive integers $a$ and $b$.
Also, we can write
$$m^2 - p^k = 2^r t$$
for some positive integers $r$ and $t$. (Note that $r \geq 2$.)

I obtain
$$a = \frac{2^r + t}{2}$$
and
$$b = \frac{\left|2^r - t\right|}{2}.$$
In both cases, it then follows that $t \equiv 0 \mod 2$.
This implies that
$$m^2 - p^k \equiv 0 \pmod 8.$$
Since $m$ is odd, this would mean that
$$p^k \equiv 1 \mod 8.$$
But we know that
$$p^k = p\left(p^{\frac{k-1}{2}}\right)^2 \equiv p \equiv 1 \pmod 8.$$
However, if $p$ is a prime satisfying $p \equiv 1 \pmod 8$, then we do know that it must satisfy $p \geq 17$.

Here is my question:

Is this proof logically correct? I have doubts regarding whether
$$a = \frac{2^r + t}{2}$$
and
$$b = \frac{\left|2^r - t\right|}{2}$$
indeed holds, in general.


Given an odd perfect number of the form $p^km^2$ with $p\equiv k\equiv1\pmod{4}$, you write
$$m^2-p^k=a^2-b^2\qquad\text{ and }\qquad m^2-p^k=2^rt,$$
where $a$, $b$, $r$ and $t$ are positive integers. Then you conclude that $t$ is even, which is of course nonsensical because we can take $r$ maximal to force $t$ to be odd. The unexplained leap, to me, is

I obtain\begin{eqnarray}a&=&\frac{2^r+t}{2}\\b&=&\frac{|2^r-t|}{2}\end{eqnarray}

How do you obtain this? It is not true that
$$(a+b)(a-b)=2^rt\qquad\Rightarrow\qquad a+b=2^r\ \wedge\ a-b=t.$$

As you don't use the fact that $p^km^2$ is perfect, your claim should hold for all numbers of the form $p^km^2$ with $p\equiv k\equiv1\pmod{4}$ and $m$ odd. Any choice will easily yield a counterexample; without much thought I'll pick $13^5631^2$. Then we can write
$$m^2-p^k=631^2-13^5=26868=4\times6717=6718^2-6716^2.$$
If we write $m^2-p^k=2^rt$ then clearly $r=2$ and $t=6717$.

The only vaguely similar result I can image, is that there are positive integers $u$ and $v$ with $u+v=r$, and integers $x$ and $y$ with $xy=t$, such that
$$a+b=2^ux\qquad\text{ and }\qquad a-b=2^vy.$$
From here you can conclude that
$$a=\frac{2^ux+2^vy}{2}\qquad\text{ and }\qquad b=\frac{2^ux-2^vy}{2}.$$
Of course this tells you nothing about the parity of $t$.
